# How do I fetch only certain PHCollections?

Tags: iphone, ios8, photos, phasset

I've created three PHCollections within my app. In a different part of my app, I'm attempting to fetch them and display them in a table view. I can get all of the user created libraries by using the following code

```
    let topLevelUserCollections: PHFetchResult  = PHCollectionList.fetchTopLevelUserCollectionsWithOptions(nil)
    self.collectionsFetchResults = [topLevelUserCollections];
    self.collectionsLocalizedTitles = ["My Clips"];
    PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().registerChangeObserver(self) //With this you need to conform to PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver
```

but how can I fetch only the asset collection I want? Also, I only want video and not images, is there a way to fetch only results with videos assests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `PHCollectionList.fetchTopLevelUserCollectionsWithOptions` with a parameter of nil. But that nil is the PHFetchOptions. Those PHFetchOptions are exactly how you make this sort of specification.

In particular, if you created these collections yourself, you have their `localIdentifier` values. That is exactly what you would specify in the PHFetchOptions `predicate` to pull out those collections. You could also do it by `localizedTitle` and so on.

Comment: I think I understand in theory how to do this (I know how to pass the title as a predicate) but I don't really understand how to pass multiple value for instance how get pack photo album with three titles.

Comment: Do three queries for one title each? Or look at how to form a complex NSPredicate. Good discussion here: http://nshipster.com/nspredicate/